# forge-configurator-inventor initialize data

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to use the forge configurator inventor to create an application. However, when following this tutorial: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor#Clear-and-load-initial-data-during-app-launch-time

I am getting errors creating initial data to debug/run the application. When I run the command:
"dotnet run initialize=true" in VS code, I get the [following error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/838N5.png).

When I look in the "WebApplication\AppBundles" folder to find the "AppBundles/UpdateDrawingsPlugin.bundle.zip" file, it is not there (the other zipped files are).

Could I please have the following question answered:
How can I get this zipped file into its proper place so that I can initialize the data and run/debug debug the application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably had a compilation error for UpdateDrawingsPlugin. Would you be able to rebuild the whole solution again and check for the errors? All the plugins are compiled, zipped, and prepared in the proper place to upload to the FDA. Once you fix the error, you should run the application using `dotnet run initialize=true clear=true` to clear partially created artifacts on the FDA; this will prevent any conflicts.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but now I am running into a different issue. Now when I try to run the application using "dotnet run", I am getting an error saying "Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated".

Comment: Hi, this is not an issue that is preventing you from running the application. But you are right, it is confusing. I already made PR https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/pull/403/files which fixes it. It will appear in the main branch this week.